# Unable to catch exception

Tags: php, exception

Why doesn't the following print "Error!" but only prints the 'failed to open stream...' warning?

```
try {
    file_get_contents('www.invalid-url.com');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) doesn't throw an exception, but returns FALSE if it fails. file_get_contents is a highly primitive function. If you want more advanced feedback, use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

E.g. something like this:

```
$curl = curl_init('your URL here');

// Return the output to a string instead of the screen with CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
curl_setopt($pCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($pCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$content = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

if($info['http_code'] === 200)
{
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It returns FALSE on error, it doesn't throw and exception.

So you could use @ to suppress the warning (if required) and check the result to see if there was an error

```
$content = @file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
if ( $content === FALSE ){
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't use exceptions by default but an error message mechanism. If you want exceptions you could use a custom error handler like in http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

The more PHP'ish way would be to shutdown the error message and check the return code. Shutting down can be done globally by `error_reporting(0);` or `ini_set('display_errors', false);` or using the `@` operator.

```
<?php
if (!@file_get_contents(....)) {
    echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: Suspressing error messages never helped anyone life getting better. This isn't the way to go. If you reach a point where you must debug this code you will slap yourself against your head when you realize you've been throwing away valid debug information.

Comment: Globally suppressing errors is a very bad idea, but suppressing errors with `@` on an individual statement here and there may sometimes be the simplest solution -- even then, be aware that even supressed errors are inefficient: the error handler is always, called, even when an error is suppressed. Suppressing errors on anything that results in more than one line of PHP being executed (like an `include` or a call to a user-defined function), on the other hand, is definitely a good way to make debugging hell.

Comment: so the best idea would be to leave error reporting on while developing an turning them of globally when the code is production ready?

Comment: Frank, I consider it the best practice to disable display_Errors on the production system and log all errors. The @ makes debugging very hard ...